# How to put a CSV file online so that my Android app can read the data inside it when it is launched?

Tags: android, security, server

This is what I want in my Android Application. The problem is that I don't know whether it works like this, and whether I am on the right path.

The functioning of my app is dependent on 6 groups/pieces-of-information, like shown in the following table. The 1st column shows the name, the second and third columns show the lower and upper range of age, and the 4th and 5th columns show the range of birth year, and 6th and 7th column show the range of CGPA.

```
"Bob"  | 20 | 30 | 1990 | 1980 | 3.0 | 4.0
"Amy"  | 30 | 40 | 1980 | 1970 | 3.3 | 4.0
"Jack" | 40 | 50 | 1970 | 1960 | 2.3 | 4.0
"John" | 25 | 35 | 1995 | 1985 | 2.0 | 4.0
"Jake" | 35 | 45 | 1985 | 1975 | 3.4 | 4.0
"Zoe"  | 45 | 55 | 1975 | 1965 | 3.2 | 4.0
```

The tricky part is that the user of the app does not get their hands on this table. It is rather, sort of an **Admin, who adds, removes, or changes the values in this table.**

So I am thinking that **the only way to go about it** is that save this table online in, say a CSV file, and store it in an online server, and write a web-service (like a SOAP based web service) to access this data from the online server, and then when the application is launched, get this data from the online server by consuming the web service.

***QUESTION 1:*** Am I on the right path?

***QUESTION 2:*** I don't know nothing about online servers. Should I search for a free server which will let me put my CSV file there (for free because this is not a commercial app) and do it? Any suggestions about servers?

***QUESTION 3:*** Is there anything else/ any other aspect to consider for such an app which I am ignoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about thinking on developing a web service (I recommend a RESTful service), something you can do is encoding that data to json and make an endpoint return it, then download that data into your app (you can use some good clients like robospice, volley, etc). These clients usually come with a json decoder so you will have your data ready to easily use it.

Also you can persist your data locally and only update it everytime you call your server endpoint (see greendao).

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer.